# Почему не проходят тексты сообщений из формы обратной связи?

Tags: php, post, form, phpmailer, multipart

Всем доброй ночи. Работаю над формой связи, без ajax, на phpmailer. Сообщения приходят в следующем виде: имя, email, файл. Текст не приходит. Валидация email происходит. 3 файла из папки phpmailer: exception.php, phpmailer.php, smtp.php оставил без изменения. Почему не приходит текст сообщения?

```js
var msg = document.querySelector(".msg");
var gsapMsg = gsap.to(".msg", 0.25, {autoAlpha: 1,y: -40,ease: Expo.inOut, paused: true});
var arrInput = document.querySelectorAll('.aInput');

// Функция отправки сообщения
function send(event, php){
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
for (var i = 0,count=arrInput.length; i<count; i++) {arrInput[i].classList.remove("errorInput");}
event.target.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
showMsg("Подождите. Идёт отправка сообщения", "#b1b1b1");
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', php, true);
req.onload = function() {
event.target.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
        json = JSON.parse(this.response); // internet explorer 11
        console.log(json);

        // ЗДЕСЬ УКАЗЫВАЕМ ДЕЙСТВИЯ В СЛУЧАЕ УСПЕХА ИЛИ НЕУДАЧИ
        if (json.result == "success") {
            // если сообщение отправлено
            showMsg("Сообщение успешно отправлено", "#36AE46");
            console.log("Сообщение отправлено");
            event.target.reset();
        } else if(json.result == "email") {
            // Если указан неверный email
            showMsg("Ошибка. Неверно указан Email", "#DC352F");
            console.log("Ошибка. Неверно указан Email");
            document.querySelector("#email").classList.add("inputerror");
        } else {
            // Если произошла ошибка
            showMsg("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено", "#DC352F");
            console.log("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено");
        }

    // Если не удалось связаться с php файлом
    } else {showMsg("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status, "#DC352F");}}; 

// Если не удалось отправить запрос. Стоит блок на хостинге
req.onerror = function() {showMsg("Ошибка отправки запроса", "#DC352F");};
req.send(new FormData(event.target));
}

// Функция появления статуса отправки сообщения
function showMsg(message, color) {
msg.innerText = message;
msg.style.background = color;
gsapMsg.restart();
}

// Оформление input file
function inputFile(e) {
    el = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".count");
    if (e.target.value != '') el.innerHTML = "Выбрано файлов: " + e.target.files.length;
    else el.innerHTML = 'Прикрепить файлы';
}

// Анимация input text
for (var i = 0, count = arrInput.length; i < count; i++) {
arrInput[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
this.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
});
arrInput[i].addEventListener("blur", function() {
if (this.value == false) 
this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
});
}

// Анимация появления блоков
window.onload = function() {
var loadPage = gsap.timeline();
loadPage.to("#form", 0.7, {autoAlpha: 1,y: 0, ease: Expo.inOut});
loadPage.to(".link", 0.7, {autoAlpha: 1,y: 0, ease: Expo.inOut}, 0);
loadPage.to(".input-wrap", 0.5, {stagger: 0.15, autoAlpha: 1,y: 0, ease: Expo.inOut}, 0.35);
loadPage.to(".file-wrap, .button", 0.5, {stagger: 0.15, autoAlpha: 1,x: 0, ease: Expo.inOut}, 0.6);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #f4f7fb;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 99%;
}

#form, .link, .input-wrap, .file-wrap, .button {
visibility: hidden;
}

.file-wrap {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
}

.button {
    transform: translateX(10px);
}

#form, .input-wrap {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
}

.link {
    transform: translateY(15px);
}

.msg {
max-width: 320px;
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 7px;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 555;
}


.showmsg {
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5vh);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-5vh);
            transform: translateY(-5vh);
    -webkit-animation: shadow  0.3s 2.5s forwards ease-in-out;
            animation: shadow  0.3s 2.5s forwards ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes view {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;-webkit-transform: translateY(-5vh);transform: translateY(-5vh);}
}

@keyframes view {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity: 1;-webkit-transform: translateY(-5vh);transform: translateY(-5vh);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
to {opacity: 0;-webkit-transform: translateY(0);transform: translateY(0);}
}

@keyframes hide {
to {opacity: 0;-webkit-transform: translateY(0);transform: translateY(0);}
}


.inputerror {
  border-color: #DC352F !important;
  animation: shake 0.15s 3 forwards ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes shake {
  from {transform: translateX(0px);}
  50% {transform: translateX(3px);}
  to {transform: translateX(-3px);}
}


.link {
  max-width: 325px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin: 50px auto;

}

.link img {
  height: 35px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.link p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 90%;
}

#form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -22px rgba(25, 41, 62, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 15px 25px -22px rgba(25, 41, 62, 0.3);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

.group-input {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.input-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  width: 260px;
}

/* input */

.input-wrap label {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  color: #848e99;
}

.form-input {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 0px;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 500 17px 'Roboto';
  border: solid 1px #dde1e6;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.input-label {
  line-height: 60px;
}

.area-label {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 0 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 34px);
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  color: #848e99;
}

.active {
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
          transform: translateY(-10px);
}


/* inputfile */
.labelFile {
  width: 210px;
  height: 52px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #c7ced7;
  color: #2c3949;
  background: #f4f7fb;
}

.labelFile:hover {
  background: #E2E9F4
}

.labelFile:active {
  background: #dae1ec;
}

.inputFile {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.labelFile img {
    height: 55%;
    margin: 5% 4% 5% 8%;
}


#texta {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 34px 20px;
  font: 16px 'Roboto';
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px #dde1e6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#texta::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
}

#texta::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-clip: content-box;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 10px;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

#texta::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: none;
}

#texta::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.aInput {
    transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.aInput:hover {
  border: solid 1px #B4BBC3
}

.aInput:focus {
  border: solid 1px #6EAFFE;
}

.button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 52px;
  background: #2045cb;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 0.1s ease-in-out;
  font: 500 16px 'Roboto';
}

.button:hover {
  background: #1E41BD;
}

.button:active {
  background: #18359C;
}

.button:disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background: #b1b1b1;
}



@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 729px) {

  .group-text-input,
  .input-wrap {
    width: 100%;
  }

}

@media (max-width: 570px) {

  #form {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    padding: 30px 7vw;
  }

  .labelFile img {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .labelFile {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }

  .button {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHPMAILER</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
    <script src="js/gsap.min.js"></script>
     <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="msg" onclick="gsapMsg.reverse()">Сообщение
      </div>
    <div class="wrap">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="form" onsubmit="send(event, 'send.php')">
    <div class="group-input">
    <div class="group-text-input">
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-input aInput" autocomplete="off">
         <label for="name" class="input-label">Представьтесь</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="form-input aInput" autocomplete="off">
        <label for="email" class="input-label">Укажите почту</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <textarea name="texta" id="texta" class="aInput"></textarea>
        <label for="texta" class="area-label">Сообщение</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file-wrap">
        <label for="myfile" class="labelFile">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/upload-to-cloud.png" alt="img"/>
            <p class="count">Прикрепить файлы</p>
        </label>
        <input type="file" multiple class="inputFile" id="myfile" name="file[]" onchange="inputFile(event)"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="button right">Отправить</button>
    </form>
     </div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
   <?php
// Файлы phpmailer
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';

// Переменные, которые отправляет пользователь
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$file = $_FILES['file'];

// Формирование самого письма
$title = "Заголовок письма";
$body = "
<h2>Новое письмо</h2>
<b>Имя:</b> $name<br>
<b>Почта:</b> $email<br><br>
<b>Сообщение:</b><br>$text
";

// Валидация почты
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

// Настройки PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();   
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {$GLOBALS['status'][] = $str;};

    // Настройки вашей почты
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.yandex.ru'; // SMTP сервера вашей почты
    $mail->Username   = 'login'; // Логин на почте yandex без @yandex.ru
    $mail->Password   = 'password'; // Пароль на почте yandex
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('mymail@mail.ru', 'Александр'); // Адрес моей почты на mail.ru и имя отправителя

    // Получатель письма
    $mail->addAddress('myyandexmail@yandex.ru');  // Адрес моей почты yandex
   

    // Прикрипление файлов к письму
if (!empty($file['name'][0])) {
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($file['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($file['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $file['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
            $rfile[] = "Файл $filename прикреплён";
        } else {
            $rfile[] = "Не удалось прикрепить файл $filename";
        }
    }   
}
// Отправка сообщения
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->Body = $body;    

// Проверяем отравленность сообщения
if ($mail->send()) {$result = "success";} 
else {$result = "error";}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = "error";
    $status = "Сообщение не было отправлено. Причина ошибки: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
} else {
    $result = "email";
}
// Отображение результата
echo json_encode(["result" => $result, "resultfile" => $rfile, "status" => $status]);

?>
```

И такой вопрос: вот эти строки правильно заполнены? В Php не силен, просьба пояснить. Заранее благодарен.

```
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.yandex.ru'; // SMTP сервера вашей почты
    $mail->Username   = 'login'; // Логин на почте yandex без @yandex.ru
    $mail->Password   = 'password'; // Пароль на почте yandex
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('mymail@mail.ru', 'Александр'); // Адрес моей почты на mail.ru и имя отправителя

    // Получатель письма
    $mail->addAddress('myyandexmail@yandex.ru');  // Адрес моей почты yandex
```

Comment: Потому что название инпута с сообщением - `texta`.

Answer (score 0):

Поищите:

Посмотрите в "инструментах разработчика браузера", какой запрос по сети идет? с текстом?

Сделайте `echo $body`, `echo $text`

Comment: 'echo $body, echo $text' как сконфигурировать?

Comment: кого сконфигурировать?
`echo json_encode("result"` работает? тогда пошлите себе обратно $body и $text для контроля.